# How long can I shower with tub chips?

Tags: bathtub, damage, porcelain

My tub has recently developed some 1" to 1 1/2" tub chips. I've already purchased the porcelain repair touch-up solution, but haven't gotten around to applying it yet. See the following photo.

[image: Tub Chips]

How long can we go on using the tub, and what are the side effects?

Comment: Those aren't tub chips.  That is paint peeling. That is not porcelain. That's some kind of paint finish on plastic.

Comment: Don't tempt the rust demons.

Comment: @Harper Apparently that's paint peeling off plastic.

Comment: Oh! Then get thee to a chandlery. They know how to fix fiberglass.

Comment: @Harper there's nothing wrong with the actual fiber glass. It seems like the paint finish (or whatever it is) is just peeling off.

Comment: @snoopy I was thinking more chandleries know exactly how to paint fiberglass that is in frequent contact with water. The last painter, not so much.  Is it possible what's failing is an amateur repaint of the shower i.e. Not the factory finish? Super easy to make prep mistakes on fiberglass that touches water a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be a porcelain tub painted over with an epoxy paint that was not done correctly.  An epoxy paint over porcelain requires proper preparation of the surface.  This does not appear to have sanding done prior to application.  So best recommendation on a low budget is to buff with a tiger disc all the existing epoxy.  Then clean extensively to remove soap scum and contaminants on the porcelain surface.  Then call a qualified porcelain re-finisher to do a professional job.  If this is a fiberglass tub,  do the same as above and call a fiberglass re-finisher to do it correctly.  Or replace the tub.  Mold and rust are not something you want in your home or in your body...